# Button element styled with CSS is not showing the background-image in IE6

Tags: html, css, button, internet-explorer-6, background-image

I have a legacy web application that is targeted for IE 6 and is being reskinned. The buttons are having the default browser button look replaced with a blue button image.

[image: Button in IE8]
[image: Button in IE6]

My following HTML and CSS works fine on IE 8, but not in IE 6.

**HTML**

```
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

**CSS**

```css
button
{
    width: 110px;
    height: 28px;
    background-image: url('../images/button.png');
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0px none #ff0000;
    cursor: hand;
    font-family: Myriad Pro, Helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Using CSS, how can I get the background image to show in IE 6?

Ideally the fix could be put in an ie6.css to make it easy to remove when IE6 support is eventually dropped.

---

Please no comments about dropping support for IE6. This legacy application is designed only for IE6 and used internally at an organisation where IE6 is the ONLY supported browser.

Comment: I know, I know, but... just drop support for nice things in IE6, people will get the message :) http://ie6countdown.com/

Comment: Think about it this way - no one who's using IE6 cares about how the web looks. So minitech is right, just don't worry about it :). It's accessible and that's what matters.

Comment: I would **LOVE** to get rid of support for IE 6, but at this organisation IE6 is still the only supported browser. The application is for internal use only. So unfortunately it is not an option.

Comment: Unless you require that button to perform the submit action, you could replace it with a `<a>` and just style it like a button. Functionality wise, it'll behave the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `background` CSS property instead of the `background-image` property does the trick as described in this [blog post](http://balajiramesh.wordpress.com/2008/09/06/button-background-image-with-css/) (excerpt below).

> The background-image property that worked in Firefox 2.0 just did not
>   have any effect on IE6. After a bit of googling, I realized that the
>   background-image property will not work on IE and that we need to use
>   the background property.

This is what works for me:

```
button
{
    background: transparent url('../images/button.png') no-repeat top;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the recesses of my memory on IE6 serve me well, it does not recognize `background-image` on a `button` element. Nothing you can do about it.

Although, again based on memory, if you can change it to an `input` (attribute `type="image"`) you might be able to get the effect you want even on IE6.