# input type=image - onclick(), will trigger its event , but not act well on function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

(I think this could be two posts - 2 questions.. so if you'll comment on it... I will separate those)

the main issue is acually:

**how could I set an image-background for a button... easy & properly ?**

I think that now I could be sure about these facts:

as I had a "little" problem with setting image as button-background ,
...I thought, ok, if it's difficult to set `<input type='button'>` with image-background, why not ***instead*** , just set `onclick` event on a `<input type='image'>`!

and I was right(...almost), cause yes, to set click-event on  `image` type is easy, also,  to set `src` ..instead of `background-image` for button... at least for me, it is.

the problem is, in current project), using a jQuery-UI  `dialog - ok, cancel`,

seems that the problem is that image-type , Posts back (?!), so dialog disappears

and button does not  cause this flaw.

I tried to debug it with a break-point, in vs2010 and it both ok with a click event as they both get to the point of "function entry" ... so with the image type ... i could only notes, as i could see the `<- Back button`, toggles from `disabled` to be clickable, so it means it did post back.

and that does not happen with a button , as you hover over the button nothing happans , and with image you could see a link in status bar .

so there **is** a difference (a real one), between button-"convert" into image,  than an image turned into a "button" (attaching it with a `Click()` event) ,

so what i would like to know , is: (only if I am allowed **this time** to use this post for both answers as they realy relate)

**why does image post back?** could i disable this action?
 ...it is not a server control. is that something you should know, and that ***suppose*** to happen ?

again if it is off-topic i would move this question, and i do need a propper way to set the background image for a button unless there's a workaround for it's behavior.

Comment: Input elements with type "image" work just like submit buttons, but were designed for server-side image maps and also pass the x/y click coordinates to the server.

Comment: Also, if you don't care for older browsers, you can just add a background image to a `<button>` element with CSS (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595258/button-element-styled-with-css-is-not-showing-the-background-image-in-ie6). BTW, you don't seem to be using jQueryUI's default method to add buttons to a dialog, you should look into that.

Comment: @bfavaretto i will start from now thanks for commenting it and for that information and about x,y sent to server via image , clients click...nice ah...i now remember old school image maps... i remeber it was cool when it was out (or atleast for my knowlege) more than 10 years ago now i can connect it to that means it is by default ment to a sort of a link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why the image type input element behaves differently than the button type, but if I were you I would avoid it all together. If you are looking to customize your button (which it appears you are) I would suggest using a div and control the user interaction via jquery/javascript.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jrb9249/BvTD5/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="div_button">
        <p>Click Me!</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.div_button').click(function(){
    alert('Run a postback via JS');
});
```

CSS:

```
.div_button
{
    border: solid 1px gray;
    width:80px;
    height:25px;
    background:#A3A3A3;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:50px;
}

.div_button:hover
{
    border: solid 1px blue;
    background:#A1A1A1;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

To add some finishing touches to complete the button look, just add some rounded corners using the jquery rounded corners plugin found [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/). And if you need to do a post back with this control (it doesn't look like an asp.net control so I don't think that is what you are doing) you can use the __Postback technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305954/asp-net-postback-with-javascript).

I hope this helps, good luck with your site.

---

**Update:**
Since this post I've started enclosing my div tags within an `<a>` tag to create a hyperlink out of the div. You can then apply custom click events to the `<a>` element and have greater control over the button you created.

Comment: forgot to thank you . that's how i aventualy made it passed this stage of progress through my current project realy cool way to over come that issue Thaks mate!