# Validate AJAX Toolkit Combobox Regular Expression Validator

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I was wondering if it was possible to validate the `ajax toolkit combobox` with a regular expression validator.  I allow the user to enter values, but only want certain values ( `regex [0-9]{0,1}[0-9]{1}|-7|-8|-9`) to be allowed.  I could use the custom validator, but I would need to also create javascript function to validate on the client side.  If there is a better way I would love to hear it.  Thanks.  Here is the combobox code:

```
    <asp:ComboBox CssClass="required" DropDownStyle="Simple"  
     ID="DaysDeployed" Width="50" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="" Value="" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Refused" Value="-7" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Don't Know" Value="-8" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Missing Data" Value="-9" />
    </asp:ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Summary: Instead of using an asp.net button that would normally trigger your postback, make one using html. Have the html button run a javascript function that first checks the regex validation, then (if valid) runs the postback function.

**First**, I would remove the asp.net button that you use to trigger the server-side code, and replace it with a client-side button. You can follow the steps in another answer of mine if you need help creating this button. Here is the link:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062993/input-type-image-onclick-will-trigger-its-event-but-not-act-well-on-funct/14063911#14063911-Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062993/input-type-image-onclick-will-trigger-its-event-but-not-act-well-on-funct/14063911#14063911)

**Second**, the javascript function should first validate the data using a regex function. Use something like this:

```
function validateCombobox(myComboboxValue) { 
    if(myComboboxValue.match(regularExpressionString)===null){
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    };
};
```

***Note: Regex is a weak area for me so you may need to revise this script a little.

**Third**, if the input is validated using the script above, then call the postback using javascript. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Create an  on the asp page. This is necessary
   because without it, the site will not generate event handlers for
   the needed buttonclick event.
2. Set the link-button's css display property to 'none'. Beware that
   link-button's "Visible" attribute my be set to true (this is because
   asp.net does not even render the code for controls with a false
   visible attribute). To illustrate, if your link-button's cssClass
   name is myButton, add this to your css file:

   ```
   .myButton
   {
      display: none;
   }
   ```
3. Now that the button is created and properly hidden, you can add the
   postback function to your javascript function. The postback function
   has two parameters, the first is the *client side ID* of the
   link-button control that we created. **Beware** that the client-side
   IDs of asp.net controls are not the same as the ID you assign it
   during development. Because of this, we use <%=Control.ClientId %>
   to get the control's *client ID*. If your link-button ID is
   "myLinkButton", the following should be your postback function:

   ```
   __doPostBack('<%=myLinkButton.clientid %>','')
   ```

   Please note that there are **two** underscore characters in the
   beginning of this function.

---

Here is an example of the regex validation function and the javascript function that should be called by your new button:

```
function validateCombobox(myComboboxValue) { 
    if(myComboboxValue.match(regularExpressionString)===null){
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    };
};


function comboBoxButton_click(){
   var myComboboxValue = $('#<%=myComboBox.clientid %>').val();
   if(validateCombobox(myComboboxValue)==true){
      __doPostBack('<%=myLinkButton.clientid %>','');
   };
};
```

I have a lot of distractions at the moment and am a little scatter-brained, so forgive me if these instructions are a little confusing. If you need more assistance, feel free to comment and I'll check back soon.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed reply, though I am looking first to see if I can use the regularexpression validator.  Thanks though.